# conditional statement result directly in bash without using if

Tags: linux, bash, shell-script, shell, command

output the name of the file with more lines, and how many more it has (one space between the name and number). If there is a tie, the output should be "foobar 0". eg: foo has 1 more line: "foo 1"; bar has 3 more lines: "bar 3", same # lines: "foobar 0".  NO IF statements.

why is this not working: `[[ $r -gt 0 ]] && { echo foo $r; } || [[ $r -lt 0 ]] && { echo bar $r; } || { echo foobar $r; }` $r is the difference between the 2 files

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With round brackets, it works like described: `([[ $r -gt 0 ]] && { echo foo $r; }) || ([[ $r -lt 0 ]] && { echo bar $r; }) || { echo foobar $r; }`

Answer (score 3):

Note that your cases are disjoint, so you don't actually need the `||`.

```
[[ $r -gt 0 ]] && echo foo $r;     # positive 
[[ $r -lt 0 ]] && echo bar $r;     # negative
[[ $r -eq 0 ]] && echo foobar $r;  # zero
```

> why is this not working

`&&` and `||` evaluate from left to right, there's no difference in the precedence between them, which makes it hard to do `if .. then .. else` style logic with them.
You need to add grouping manually with braces or parenthesis. (Or just use the `if` statement, it's there for a reason.)

For example, this always prints `nonnegative`, regardless of if the `negative` prints:

```
[ $x -ge 0 ]] || echo negative && echo nonnegative
```

If you want the difference as a positive value, you'll need to negate it in the middle branch, e.g.:

```
[[ $r -lt 0 ]] && echo bar $(( -r ));
```